# Create Series chart from Object within Object: Crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have an object

```
{
        "AmountExpectedPay" : 300,
        "AmountToPayToVendor" : 100,
        "Category" : "DME",
        "Current" : "Step 5",
        "Date" : "1/2/2019",
        "Employee" : "JB",
        "GrossProfit" : 0,
        "Margin" : 
        {
            "ActualIncomeActualPayment" : 1.19808,
            "ActualIncomeExpectedPayment" : 1.19808,
            "ExpectedIncomeActualPayment" : 1,
            "ExpectedIncomeExpectedPayment" : 0.760410013079052
        }
```

This represents a Purchase Order. I have 5504 of these.

I would like to graph these in DC JS as a series chart, but as I understand DC, The series chart needs these broken into four separate records(Objects), one record for each type of margin so that Crossfilter can group by type and DC JS render each type as a line.

However, is there a way to use CrossFilter's reduce methods to pseudo create one series for each type for the series chart?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: The easiest solutions are going to involve creating a group for each of the values. The series chart just generates a composite chart, so one solution is to create a group for each of the values and then build a composite chart out of it. Or take a look at [this question, which I believe is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313909/dc-js-create-series-plot-using-multiple-columns). My answer wasn't accepted or upvoted so I can't mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: That's @Gordon I will take a look at that question as well.